# Why does AJAX return the same data to the callback when I pass different objects in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to make 2 different calls to a MVC controller.  The first returns a series of data the second returns a partial view.  In firebug I see the results and status is "success" on both.

I am trying to pass in a callback to handle the result to a common AJAX method.  First is dataType 'Json" second is dataType 'HTML'.  Again, they both work if I fire them individually but they seem to overwrite each other on the second call.

Here are my global params that get appended all inside the object:

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    data: '',
    params: {},
    callback: "ajaxafter",
    url: "",
    ishtml: false,
    tag: 0,
    success: false
};

...
    //  get ajax options
me.getAjaxOptions = function () {
    return ajaxOptions;
}

p.AJAX = (function ($, me) {
    'use strict';
    var child = {};

    function returnAJAXDefault(o) {
        var dataType = (o.ishtml) ? "html" : "json";

        $.ajax({
            url: o.url,
            data: JSON.stringify(o.params),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: dataType,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'         
        }).done(function (data) {
            o.data = data;
            o.success = true;

            console.dir(o)
            if (o.callback !== null && me[o.callback]) {
                me[o.callback](o);
                return;
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXhR) {
            o.data = jqXhR;
            if (o.callback !== null && me[o.callback]) {
                me[o.callback](o);
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    //  get ajax
    child.getAJAX = function (options) {
        returnAJAXDefault(options);
    }

    return child;

}(jQuery, obj));
```

This is my ajax call.

On the page I try and do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    p = (function ($, me) {
        me.ajaxafter = function (data) {
            console.log(1)
            if (data.tag == 1) {
                $('body').html(data.data)
            }

            if (data.tag == 0) {
                console.dir(data.data);
            }
        }

        me.ajaxafter1 = function (data) {
            console.log(2)
            if (data.tag == 1) {
                $('body').html(data.data)
            }

            if (data.tag == 0) {
                console.dir(data.data);
            }
        }

        function test1() {
            var axopts = me.getAjaxOptions();
            axopts.params = {
                varinput: 'tst'
            };
            axopts.url = "/Common/ReturnProjectList";
            axopts.callback = "ajaxafter";
            me.AJAX.getAJAX(axopts);

        }

        function test2() {
            var axopts1 = me.getAjaxOptions();
            axopts1.url = "/Common/ReturnPartial";
            axopts1.ishtml = true;
            axopts1.tag = 1;
            axopts1.callback = "ajaxafter1";
            me.AJAX.getAJAX(axopts1);

        }

        test1();
        test2();

    }(jQuery, obj));

});
```

The results from firebug are attached.

Please let me know if my question can be better worded.  Keep getting thumbs down.

Also, if my code can be improved I'd love to know but, really looking for why the returns aren't independent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects are passed by pointer in Javascript so when you call `me.getAjaxOptions()` and pass that to your ajax call, **you are passing the exact same `ajaxOptions` object to both ajax calls**.  No copy is made.  It is the exact same object.  So, **since you're putting return results into that object, a 2nd ajax call will overwrite the results of the first ajax call.**

Many of your design practices in this code are what are leading to your issue.  First, you can bypass this entire issue if you return results in a new object that is created by the function that receives the results. Then, you NEVER have an opportunity for the results of one call to overwrite the results of a prior call.

And, I'd really recommend that you NOT design a new callback system on top of the existing callback system that already exists.  There's really no reason.  My #1 recommendation would be to just use the Promise that jQuery already returns for each Ajax call since it is a richly designed system for communicating results back from an asynchronous operation like an Ajax call.

And, if you're going to design a new callback system, then passing a callback by property name as a string is very odd and really not necessary.  Callbacks can be passed as a direct function reference.

FYI, since you have jQuery, you can use `$.extend()` to make an actual copy of an object to work around this issue, but I'd suggest a redesign that use the built-in promise system for returning async results as this is considered the "modern" and more capable way of dealing with async operations now (becoming standard in ES6 - functionality already in jQuery).

Comment: That helped a ton!.  Thank you for you detailed response.  I will take both of your suggestions and implement!.